# Can we build .xap from mobilefirst without having visual studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Could we generate windows8 deployable binaries/.xap from mobilefirst without having visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst Studio does not generate "deployables" (binary files such as .xap, .ipa, .apk, .bar and so on) for any of its supported environments. You must use either Xcode, Android Studio, Visual Studio or any other supported tool *by the required environment* in order to generate its "deployable".

Comment: So for generating windows8.1 tablet deployable, is it mandatory to have   Visual Studio 2013 installed in WINDOWS8.1 OS ? Also wat is the final deployable for windows8.1 tablet ? Is it .appx or .xap?

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory. I don't know what MS chose for it. Check the MS documentation for Windows OS.